# How to use curl library code (not command, i want to use libcurl as static lib) to display/downloads/uploads file from google drive using c++?

Tags: c++11, google-drive-api, libcurl

How to use curl library code (i dont want to use the curl command, i want to use libcurl as static lib) to display/downloads/uploads file from google drive using c++?

Earlier Google APIs Client Library for C++ (http://google.github.io/google-api-cpp-client/latest/index.html) was available but now it is deprecated.

Advance Thanks for help,
RCJ

Comment: 1 way can think of is to use google auth services to generate links to your drive contents. Then use those urls with the curl lib to operate on them. An example is here: https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2018/03/13/using-curl-library-from-c-on-windows/

Comment: At stackoverflow we don't write entire programs for people. We help out with specific problems, so you should rather proceed and write your code and ask if you run into problems.